# Why is web application not finding directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, webserver

This is my app settings tag

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ReportDirectory" value="\\netowrkserver\Users\user\Documents\DailyReport\" />
</appSettings>
```

This is the code SNIPPET from my global.asax.cs file

```
string dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDirectory"]; 
excelworkBook.SaveAs(@dir + member.Teamname.ToString().Trim() + "DailyReport.xlsx");
```

When I run this code locally, it does what it should do which is create an excel file in the specified directory in the app settings code. However when I deploy the web application to IIS, it does not create the file. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does the account the site is running on have permissions to access that path?

Comment: Well, what Exception does the logging tell you happens? Or do you lack those vital debugging informations?

Comment: So many choices. User it runs as doesn't have permissions to the share or path most likely. Firewall might be involved. Or, you're using COM and it's not installed on the server. (excel workbook)

Comment: If you don't have your own log or tracing, you might find something in the networkserver's event log that will help narrow down the cause.

Comment: @nikki9696 I’m using Microsoft.office.Interop NuGet package. At first I was getting COM error because the Interop dell was not deployed or seen in the bin folder. However that has been fixed and it is now in the bin folder and I don’t get the COM error again. Actually I don’t get ANY error that’s the problem. I don’t get any exception but the file is still not created.

Comment: @Christipher yes My account has permissions because I have access to the server and I can create file and directories

Comment: Guys Thank you for the advices really! But my logs show nothing because there seem to be no exception. The file just don’t get created. Weird. When I get back to the network tomorrow I will check the event logs to see what exactly is going on(if there is none)